# How to get image from Google static map API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use this code to generate static images from Google API, but I have too many requests, so sometimes I get overuse from Google.

```
string latlng = location.Latitude + "," + location.Longitude;
string path = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latlng +
   "&zoom=16&size=200x200&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C" +
   latlng + "&sensor=false";
```

Is it possible to call this from C# to generate and save images? I can't find way to get an image object.

Comment: Is this a web application (you did tag it with asp.net-mvc)? If so, do you generate an img tag and let the browser fetch the image, or do you need it server side?

Comment: Yes I need it on the server side. I accepted @L.B answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
  wc.DownloadFile(url, @"c:\temp\img.png");
}
```

Comment: you are a Saint!